# How can I disable React Query Devtools in my playwright visual tests?

Tags: playwright, react-query

I want to use **Playwright** for local visual regression testing. The problem is I have **ReactQuery Devtools** installed and so my visual snapshots all have that open and displayed, covering up a bunch of the content I want to protect against visual regressions. [image: ReactQuery Devtools]

I could make it so the test clicks the close button. That would mean I only get the little ReactQuery icon displayed, but if these tests work well I may want to use them in CI, so I don't really want any visual discrepancies between local and CI renders.

What I'm wondering is if there's something I could put in my test to disable the Devtools even though `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`.

Note: I tried launching the tests, and the dev server with the NODE_ENV environment variable set to `testing`. NextJS warned me that was a bad idea, and it did nothing to help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally render the dev tools based on a bespoke environment variable.

```
{process.env.REACT_APP_SHOW_DEV_TOOLS : <ReactQueryDevtools/> ? null}
```

Add `REACT_APP_SHOW_DEV_TOOLS=false` to your playwrite envrionment variables.

Comment: Thank you Slava, that's exactly what I ened up doing. Note to others, this variable needs to be set on your server, not on the playwright process, if they are different :)

Answer (score 1):

devtools are automatically disabled in production only. The question is why are the devtools open? Are you rendering them with `initialIsOpen` ?

If not, it's potentially because you've opened them manually and this is persisted to localStorage, so that they will be in the same state the next time you visit the page. If that is the case, you could potentially let your playwright tests run in an [incognito mode](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsercontext) to avoid sharing the same localstorage:

```
// Create a new incognito browser context
const context = await browser.newContext();
// Create a new page inside context.
const page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');
// Dispose context once it's no longer needed.
await context.close();
```

Comment: Yes they are rendered with initialIsOpen. This is potentially useful stuff though, thanks :)